# How to get effective Bounds of a subview in its parent view's co-ordinate system

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, subview

In my app, I allow the user to annotate a photo by adding arrows (custom ArrowView). There can be many arrows added, with various zoom & rotation.

I am trying implement selecting of arrow by touch. Currently, I am iterating & using

```
CGRectContainsPoint(arrowView.frame, touchPoint)
```

to decide which arrow to select based on a touch gesture.

But, this does not work well when some of the arrows are big & rotated to 45 degrees (since the frame becomes big).

Question:
I would like to use bounds of the arrow translated to parent co-ordinates instead of frame. How can I get this when scaling & rotation is applied?

Alternatively, is there a better method to solve this selection problem?

Comment: *bounds of the arrow translated to parent co-ordinates* is the definition of *frame*. Can you post more code than the line you posted to show how you defined touchPoint?

Comment: but frame becomes bigger when rotated, while bounds remains same. I would like to get the original frame with rotation applied (ie., the rectangle's sides may not be parallel to the parent view frame's sides). This is what I meant by "bounds of the arrow translated to parent co-ordinates".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code find the arrow under `touchPoint`:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    UIView *arrow = [self.view hitTest:touchPoint withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: sch, Thanks for the answer. However, I am using `UITapGestureRecognizer` for the same. Is it possible to get `UIEvent` corresponding to the tapGesture ?